# Random touch problem!

Tags: huawei, touchscreen

**Huawei G8**
In this phone when i do some heavy stuff like play a game or may be randomly twice in a day my phone touch become irresponsive. Restarting from power button also don't work when i even touch restart!
Swipe on screen don't work like unlocking via swipe or swiping notification bar. although launcher pages do swiped. I go to home screen either via finger print unlock or opening camera and then going to home screen.
It get fixed after force restart.
 So i want to know that what kind of problem is this. Soft or hard side?

Comment: If the problem occurs does anything works in this situation (e.g. notification of new message)? If not may be the system has just crashed and you only see the last image before the crash.

Comment: yes. i notice that certain operations don't work like pressing power button and then touch on power off or restart don't work although other function like volume control with touch works!